# No constructor found for a user-created class

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

This may be hard to explain. There's this snippet of code:

```
void user_choice(string f) {
    bool goodchoice;
    string file = f;
    while (!goodchoice) {
        string answer;
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == "save") {
            Data(file, "05/05/2014");
            goodchoice = true;
        }
        else if (answer == "look") {
            Data(file);
            goodchoice = true;
        }
        else cout << "I don't understand that. Please try again." << endl;
    }
}
```

I have a class called `Data` with these constructors:

```
Data(string n);
Data(string n, string d);
```

I included the Data.h header file in my main CPP file. The if-statement for 'save' works fine, but the if-statement for 'look' tells me that there is no default constructor for Data even though there is. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Have you defined (provided a body) for `Data(string n);`

Comment: As an aside, you'll want to initialise `goodchoice` to `false`, otherwise it's 50/50 whether you'll ever enter the while loop.

Comment: @TristanBrindle, 50% in, 50% out, 50% nasal demons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Data(file);
```

This is not calling the constructor taking a string. Instead, it's declaring an object of `Data` named `file` and using the default constructor to do it. It's the same thing as:

```
Data file;
```

I can't remember 100% why this behaviour exists, but I believe it was inherited from C. You should be able to find more examples of this by relating it to the Most Vexing Parse, as this happens quite a bit in relation to that.

Funnily enough, this isn't one of those situations where you can fix it by adding another set of parentheses. I am unaware of the accepted method of making this call the constructor (probably for the better, as noted below), but casting is one option, and calling a function another, though both seem unnatural:

```
Data((file)); //doesn't work
Data(static_cast<string>(file)); //works
(void)Data(file); //works

template<typename T>
T &self(T &arg) {
    return arg;
}

Data(self(file)); //works
```

Unless the constructors have side effects, these will not do anything meaningful, just create and destroy an object. I'm honestly not sure what these statements are meaning to accomplish. If the constructor is responsible for performing an action and you only need temporary objects, make `Data` a function instead. If you want to use the instance to call a member function on it or similar, you should store the instance in a variable so you can use that variable to do what it needs to do. The above "fixes" should all be shallow workarounds to a deeper problem.

Answer (score 0):

Data is a class,not an object. So,`Data(file)` calling a copy construct function.And you don't declare a copy  construct function.you need declare a object like `Data data` and `data(file)`

Comment: A copy-constructor should be implicitly generated by the compiler based on what the OP has given us.

Comment: @chris But `file` is not a object of `Data`, so  default copy constructor for Data is not suitable for `Data(file)`.

Comment: Not suitable, yes, but the copy-constructor would still exist. Defining it so it would be suitable would make it cease to be a copy-constructor. Anyway, it doesn't actually matter what type the previous `file` variable is, as this line creates a new one called `file` that shadows the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You need one of two things... one of these two constructors

```
Data();
//or
Data(string n = "default argument here");
```

You are also making an error when you say `Data(file);` because you are creating a temporary object of type "Data" by calling the constructor but you are not storing it. I think you are tying to do this.

```
void user_choice(string f) {
    bool goodchoice;
    Data myData;//this requires the constructors i listed above
    string file = f;
    while (!goodchoice) {
        string answer;
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == "save") {
            //assign to data by calling the constructor
            myData=Data(file, "05/05/2014");
            goodchoice = true;
        }
        else if (answer == "look") {
            //assign to data by calling the constructor
            myData=Data(file);
            goodchoice = true;
        }
        else cout << "I don't understand that. Please try again." << endl;
    }
}
```

I believe this should fix your problem.
Good Luck

Comment: It isn't an inherent error to create a temporary object and not store it. For example, `std::ofstream("some file") << "some data";` will compile and output "some data" to "some file". I think the true problem is the design behind why these temporaries are being created and immediately thrown away.

Comment: @chris That was the point that i was attempting to get at. If i misunderstood his question I apologize.

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell what the underlying problem is here, so don't worry.

Comment: @chris I would need to see more of the program to make a better guess t what is trying to done. It looks as if he is trying to use data() as a function call but he states that it is a class so I'm not sure. Since the constructor is being used I assume that the intent is to make a data object. I believe one design issue is the throwing away of the temp object. As far as the constructor error I'm not sure.